# Minimal distance between multiple moving obstacles using PCL

Tags: ros, pcl, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like know the minimal distances between the robot (KUKA iiwa,base-fixed) and several moving obstacles(human and other objects). All of these stuff may be moving when collaborative task is executing. I have laser scanner or Kinect V2. I think PCL library is a good start as I dont need any transform of depth images. But how can I get there? Any help??

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257850/minimal-distance-between-multiple-moving-obstacles-using-pcl/) by [pipo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29816/pipo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2017-03-25**:
Well, I have used minimal distances in OpenCV in my people counter problem. I don't know exactly on the PCL library is that you could create a tuple and append all the euclidean distances between 2D objects. Get the least one to track and use the COM of objects for calculating the euclidean distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well i have some old program which can do that, but u have to do little work on that, to complete it. First considering that only other objects are moving and your robot is stationary. First when ever your robot is in standing state i.e not moving ur robot needs to first save the 3d image of the present image, which can be done like below. Here this function simply saves the present 3d image in a ros bag called image.bag, which is used latter, or can be combined in same program.

```
    int ix = -1, iy = -1, iz = -1;
    rosbag::Bag bag("image.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Write);

    for(int k=0;k<h && ros::ok();k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<w;l++)  {
        ix = ix+1;
            x[ix].data = P[k][l].x;
        } }

    for(int k=0;k<h;k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<w;l++)  {
         iy = iy+1;
           int ix = -1, iy = -1, iz = -1;
    rosbag::Bag bag("image.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Write);

    for(int k=0;k<h && ros::ok();k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<w;l++)  {
        ix = ix+1;
            x[ix].data = P[k][l].x;
        } }

    for(int k=0;k<h;k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<w;l++)  {
         iy = iy+1;
            y[iy].data = P[k][l].y;
     } }

    for(int k=0;k<h;k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<w;l++)  {
        iz = iz+1;
        z[iz].data = P[k][l].z;
     }}

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
    bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), x[i]);
   //std::cout<<i<<"\t"<<ix<<"\t"<<"x"<<"\t"<<x[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
    bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), y[i]);
   //std::cout<<n<<"\t"<<iy<<"\t"<<"y"<<"\t"<<y[n]<<std::endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
    bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), z[i]);
   //std::cout<<i<<"\t"<<iz<<"\t"<<"z"<<"\t"<<z[i]<<std::endl;
    }

    bag.close();     y[iy].data = P[k][l].y;
     } }

    for(int k=0;k<h;k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<w;l++)  {
        iz = iz+1;
        z[iz].data = P[k][l].z;
     }}

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
    bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), x[i]);
   //std::cout<<i<<"\t"<<ix<<"\t"<<"x"<<"\t"<<x[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
    bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), y[i]);
   //std::cout<<n<<"\t"<<iy<<"\t"<<"y"<<"\t"<<y[n]<<std::endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
    bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), z[i]);
   //std::cout<<i<<"\t"<<iz<<"\t"<<"z"<<"\t"<<z[i]<<std::endl;
    }

    bag.close();
```

After saving how the 3d image is, when the robot is not moving. The next part what robot does is it analyses the present 3d image(video stream subscribed from kinect) and if any object is moving, it will detect that, and save its point clouds, and for every seperate object at distance farther than 2 cam, they are considered as differenct object and saved in different array, u can use vector for it. And it looks little long, u can shorten it. This is just the old program which i used to detect moved objects in 3d image.

```
    rosbag::Bag bag("test.bag");
    //std_msgs::Float32 i[40000], y[40000], z[40000];
   int iv = -1, ix = -1, iy = -1, iz = -1;

        rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery("numbers"));
        BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
           {
               std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr i = m.instantiate<std_msgs::Float32>();
               iv = iv+1;
               if(iv>=0 && iv<306081) {
                   ix = ix+1;
                   xv[ix] = i->data;
                     //  std::cout<<iv<<"x ="<<"\t"<<ix<<"\t"<<xv[ix]<<std::endl;
               }
               if(iv>=306081 && iv<612162)
               {
                   iy = iy+1;
                   yv[iy] = i->data;
             ip = -1;
         for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<w;j++)
             {
                 ip = ip+1;
                 x[i][j] = xv[ip]; xp[i][j] = P[i][j].x;
                 y[i][j] = yv[ip]; yp[i][j] = P[i][j].y;
                 z[i][j] = zv[ip]; zp[i][j] = P[i][j].z;          
             }
         }
      

               // ** comparing previous and present point cloud and finding moved objects
               int im = -1;
              // int m = 0;
               for(int k=0;k<h;k++)
                       {
                           for(int l=0;l<w;l++)
                           {
                               if( z[k][l]!=0 && zp[k][l]!=0 && !isnan(x[k][l]) && !isnan(xp[k][l]) && !isnan(y[k][l]) && !isnan(yp[k][l]) && !isnan(z[k][l]) && !isnan(zp[k][l]) )
                               {
                                   float dx=abs(float(x[k][l]-xp[k][l])*100);
                                   float dy=abs(float(y[k][l]-yp[k][l])*100);
                                   float dz=abs(float(z[k][l]-zp[k][l])*100);
                                   float d = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz);
                                   if(d>2)
                                   {
                                       im = im+1;
                                       a[im] = x[k][l]; b[im] = y[k][l]; c[im] = z[k][l];
                                       xa[im] = k; ya[im] = l;
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                        }
               if(im!=30000) {
                float xe[im], ye[im], ze[im];  int no[1000]; 
                for(int i=0;i<=im;i++) 
                {
                    xe[i] = a[i]; ye[i] = b[i]; ze[i] = c[i];
                }
                int ie = im;
                
                int iobj = -1; int nobj = -1;
                float xnc[ie], ync[ie], znc[ie];
                while(ie>1)
                {
                iobj = iobj+1; 
                ip = -1; int ic = -1; xc[iobj][0] = xe[0]; yc[iobj][0] = ye[0]; zc[iobj][0] = ze[0];
                while(ip<=ic && ros::ok())
                {
                    ip = ip+1; int inc = -1;
                    for(int i=0;i<=ie && ros::ok();i++)
                    {
                        if(ip!=i)
                        {
                            float d = sqrt(pow(xc[iobj][ip]-xe[i],2)+pow(yc[iobj][ip]-ye[i],2)+pow(zc[iobj][ip]-ze[i],2));
                            if(d<=0.01)
                            {
                                ic = ic+1;
                                xc[iobj][ic] = xe[i]; yc[iobj][ic] = ye[i]; zc[iobj][ic] = ze[i];
                         // if(ic%30==0) {
                          if(!isnan(xe[i]) && !isnan(ye[i]) && !isnan(ze[i]) && ze[i]!=0)
                             {
                                    p.x = ze[i]; p.y = -xe[i]; p.z = -ye[i];
                                    points.points.push_back(p); 
                                    marker_pub.publish(points);
                                } // }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                inc = inc+1;
                                xnc[inc] = xe[i]; ync[inc] = ye[i]; znc[inc] = ze[i]; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for(int j=0;j<=inc && ros::ok();j++)
                    {
                        xe[j] = xnc[j]; ye[j] = ync[j]; ze[j] = znc[j];
                    } 
                    ie = inc;  //std::cout<<"ommm"<<"\t"<<iobj<<"\t"<<ip<<"\t"<<ic<<"\t"<<inc<<std::endl;
                }
                if(ic>500) {
                nobj = nobj+1;
                for(int k=0;k<=ic;k++)
                { 
                    xobj[nobj][k] = xc[iobj][k]; yobj[nobj][k] = yc[iobj][k]; zobj[nobj][k] = zc[iobj][k];
                } no[nobj] = ic; }  }   }
               if(iv>=612162 && iv<918243) {
                   iz = iz+1;
                   zv[iz] = i->data;
                    }
        }
         bag.close();

         // ** converting already read saved points to 2 d
         int ip = -1;
         for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<w;j++)
             {
                 ip = ip+1;
                 x[i][j] = xv[ip]; xp[i][j] = P[i][j].x;
                 y[i][j] = yv[ip]; yp[i][j] = P[i][j].y;
                 z[i][j] = zv[ip]; zp[i][j] = P[i][j].z;          
             }
         }
      

               // ** comparing previous and present point cloud and finding moved objects
               int im = -1;
              // int m = 0;
               for(int k=0;k<h;k++)
                       {
                           for(int l=0;l<w;l++)
                           {
                               if( z[k][l]!=0 && zp[k][l]!=0 && !isnan(x[k][l]) && !isnan(xp[k][l]) && !isnan(y[k][l]) && !isnan(yp[k][l]) && !isnan(z[k][l]) && !isnan(zp[k][l]) )
                               {
                                   float dx=abs(float(x[k][l]-xp[k][l])*100);
                                   float dy=abs(float(y[k][l]-yp[k][l])*100);
                                   float dz=abs(float(z[k][l]-zp[k][l])*100);
                                   float d = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz);
                                   if(d>2)
                                   {
                                       im = im+1;
                                       a[im] = x[k][l]; b[im] = y[k][l]; c[im] = z[k][l];
                                       xa[im] = k; ya[im] = l;
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                        }
               if(im!=30000) {
                float xe[im], ye[im], ze[im];  int no[1000]; 
                for(int i=0;i<=im;i++) 
                {
                    xe[i] = a[i]; ye[i] = b[i]; ze[i] = c[i];
                }
                int ie = im;
                
                int iobj = -1; int nobj = -1;
                float xnc[ie], ync[ie], znc[ie];
                while(ie>1)
                {
                iobj = iobj+1; 
                ip = -1; int ic = -1; xc[iobj][0] = xe[0]; yc[iobj][0] = ye[0]; zc[iobj][0] = ze[0];
                while(ip<=ic && ros::ok())
                {
                    ip = ip+1; int inc = -1;
                    for(int i=0;i<=ie && ros::ok();i++)
                    {
                        if(ip!=i)
                        {
                            float d = sqrt(pow(xc[iobj][ip]-xe[i],2)+pow(yc[iobj][ip]-ye[i],2)+pow(zc[iobj][ip]-ze[i],2));
                            if(d<=0.01)
                            {
                                ic = ic+1;
                                xc[iobj][ic] = xe[i]; yc[iobj][ic] = ye[i]; zc[iobj][ic] = ze[i];
                         // if(ic%30==0) {
                          if(!isnan(xe[i]) && !isnan(ye[i]) && !isnan(ze[i]) && ze[i]!=0)
                             {
                                    p.x = ze[i]; p.y = -xe[i]; p.z = -ye[i];
                                    points.points.push_back(p); 
                                    marker_pub.publish(points);
                                } // }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                inc = inc+1;
                                xnc[inc] = xe[i]; ync[inc] = ye[i]; znc[inc] = ze[i]; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for(int j=0;j<=inc && ros::ok();j++)
                    {
                        xe[j] = xnc[j]; ye[j] = ync[j]; ze[j] = znc[j];
                    } 
                    ie = inc;  //std::cout<<"ommm"<<"\t"<<iobj<<"\t"<<ip<<"\t"<<ic<<"\t"<<inc<<std::endl;
                }
                if(ic>500) {
                nobj = nobj+1;
                for(int k=0;k<=ic;k++)
                { 
                    xobj[nobj][k] = xc[iobj][k]; yobj[nobj][k] = yc[iobj][k]; zobj[nobj][k] = zc[iobj][k];
                } no[nobj] = ic; }  }
```

So in this way, u have a 2 d array, xobj[][], yobj[][], zobj[][] where first index represents the index of object and second represents index of point on that object. No after u have seperated given 3d objects from the image, for each object and your robot you can calculate the minimum distance between each of those objects. By using their point coordinates which are {xobj[][],yobj[][],zobj[][]}.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0